# LinkedList with years

Tags: java, java-8

I have to code LinkedList with two positions. First is the name and the second is the year.

```
class Person
{
    String name;
    int year;

    public Person(String name, int year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
    }
}   



class LinkedListStart { 
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        LinkedList<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();
            persons.add(new Person("Joe", 2010));
        persons.add(new Person("Jane", 2012));
        persons.add(new Person("Charly", 1910));
        persons.add(new Person("Daisy", 1908));

        System.out.println("LinkedList : " + persons);
    }
}
```

There are errors when I am running the code:
LinkedList : [Person@6d06d69c, Person@7852e922, Person@4e25154f, Person@70dea4e]

Is it possible to do it? I want do use for-each loop to find person who is below 1950.
How to code something like this?

Comment: It is expected that you have at least made an attempt at solving the problem yourself, and that you show that attempt. You cannot add to a list like that. You could use a map, or a list of objects containing two fields.

Comment: If the assignment is literally like this, you are most probably expected to add these elements in a consistent pattern, e.g. names at even indices and years at odd. Just two `add` calls instead of one with two arguments.

Comment: Don’t call your own class `LinkedList` when you intend to use the standard `LinkedList` within that class. Unless you are supposed to implement your own linked list. In that case, you can only use the features you have also implemented.

Comment: doing `System.out.println(new Person("name", 2000));` will return similar output - please override (add) a `toString()` method to the `Person` class (e.g. `@Override public String toString() {  return name + " " + year; }`)

Comment: @user85421-Banned How to add this to my code?

Comment: add it inside the block `{ }` for the `Person` class, just before the closing `}` - but that is really essential, better do some basic tutorials

Comment: @tellarwind I have attached the code as an answer. Use that one.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine them both into one `String` like `names.add("Joe 2010")` (**NOT** a recommended, or particularly good approach) or create a `Person` class to include both of these attributes, but you can't add two elements in the space of one, like you are attempting to do with your code above.

If you go with the `Person` class route, iterate through each element, and check if `Person.year` or whatever you choose to call the attribute is less than 1950.

If you go with the `String` route, iterate through each, split the `String` on a space to create an array, where the first element is the name and the second is the year, parse an `int` out of the year `String` using `Integer.parseInt` and then check if the year is less than 1950. As @Michael mentioned, combining two strings like this is not recommended

**Edit**: As for your new problem, Java's `LinkedList<T>` class is known as a generic class, because it takes a type parameter, such as the `Person` part in `LinkedList<Person>`. Because your class is not defined as a generic class, and has the same name as the built-in `LinkedList`, you are receiving this error when you try to pass in a type parameter, as Java thinks you are trying to use your own `LinkedList` class. In general, even if you are not using a particular built-in class in your code, it's best not to name your own classes with the same name as built-ins, so collisions like this don't happen. Simply rename your own class, and your code will work

Comment: Concatenating strings is a bad idea. What if my name is André 3000?

Comment: @Michael sure but I'm going with OP's example of where the name is one word without a space, and also considering that they might want to stick with using strings

Comment: @Michael I understand where you're coming from and fully agree that it's not a good idea, but I was trying to cover all the potential applications OP has for this data in case, for example, they require using strings for some unknown reason

Comment: @Michael agreed, I should have explicitly and obviously mentioned that that was not a good approach, before you brought it up in the comments

Comment: There are errors:
 type LinkedList does not take parameters, line 24 type LinkedList does not take parameters, line 24

Comment: @tellarwind You have moved the goalposts somewhat. You should have included that in the first place. Suggest deleting the question and asking another. You have effectively invalidated the existing answers

Comment: @tellarwind as @Holger mentioned in the comments on your post, you're naming your class with the same name as a built-in class which is never a good idea, but in this case because you're also importing the `LinkedList` class, it will conflict

Comment: @tellarwind Java's `LinkedList` class is known as a generic class, because it takes a type parameter, such as the `Person` part in `LinkedList<Person>`. Because your class is not defined as a generic class, and has the same name as the built-in `LinkedList`, you are receiving this error when you try to pass in a type parameter

Answer (score 0):

You should define a class Person as follows:

```
class Person{
        String name;
        int year;
        public Person(String name, int year) {
            this.name = name;
            this.year = year;
        }
}
```

And then create a `LinkedList` as follows:

```
LinkedList<Person> persons = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a custom list here is the code,
create a class name it what ever you want, i named it HomeDataModel

```
public class HomeDataModel {

private String name;
private int year;


public HomeDataModel() {
}

public HomeDataModel(String name,int year) {

    name=name;
    year= year;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    name= name;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    year= year;
}
}
```

now in your activity where you want to use list,,

```
//creating a custom list
List<HomeDataModel> listname = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new HomeDataModel("yourname", "Youryear"));
//code for check how is below 1950 
for(int i=0; i<listname.size(); i++){
int check = list.get(i).getYear();
if(check <1950){
String newname = list.get(i).getName(); //the name is stored
Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,newname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't wanna use: ArrayList and I have to use for-each loop.

Comment: I have updated my question after all comments. Can you check now?

Comment: System.out.println("LinkedList : " + persons);
here is the error i think ,, you are getting the whole model  actullay, 
from a list you have to get the desired itme like this 
persons.get(1).getname();
persons.get(1).getyear();
But firts you have to make getter, setter in your persons class.

Comment: persons(index).getname();
persons(index).getyear();
//from which index you want to get the vaule 
may be now you get the point?

Comment: Mubashir Murtaza, public String getYear() {
    return year;
incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String,

Comment: brother i consider its better to use string always,, for in your person class you can set years as string, and when you call it like String year = listname.get(index).getYears, you will recive a string, now you can use that string, 
if you want to use its as a interger you can conver string to interger by int  y= Integer.parseInt(year); //the year string that you recive is now a integer ,, 
if you want to convert interger to string just use String.valueof(interger);

Answer (score 0):

> There are errors when I am running the code: LinkedList : [Person@6d06d69c, Person@7852e922, Person@4e25154f, Person@70dea4e]

Every class in Java has the toString() method in it by default, which is called if you pass some object of that class to System.out.println(). By default, this call returns the className@hashcode of that object.
Here you have not overridden the toString method that's why it is printing like that by default.Please us below code:

```
public class Test {

static class Person
{
    String name;
    int year;

    public Person(String name, int year) {
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", year=" + year + "]";
    }


} 


        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            LinkedList<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();
            persons.add(new Person("Joe", 2010));
            persons.add(new Person("Jane", 2012));
            persons.add(new Person("Charly", 1910));
            persons.add(new Person("Daisy", 1908));

            for (Person person : persons) {
                System.out.println("Name is::"+person.name+" year is:::"+person.year);
            }

            //for printing the person override tostring method
            System.out.println(persons);
}
```

}